# How to align on-demand in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, report

I wrote one DAX formula in Power BI. The result from this DAX formula is either a number or a blank. If the result is a number, align it to the right, if the result is blank, align it to the middle. How can I do that?

```
Yeni Teminatlı = IF(

ISBLANK(
    CALCULATE(
    SUM(Hamdata[Hedef_Tutar]), 
    FILTER(Hamdata, Hamdata[GroupBuName] = "Teminatli"), 
    FILTER(Hamdata, Hamdata[Hedef_Tutar] <> 0)
             ) 
       ), " - ",
   
    CALCULATE(
    SUM(Hamdata[Hedef_Tutar]), 
    FILTER(Hamdata, Hamdata[GroupBuName] = "Teminatli"), 
    FILTER(Hamdata, Hamdata[Hedef_Tutar] <> 0)
             ) 
                 )




The result is as follows. Put the "-" sign because the result is not a number. But when this mark is present I want it to be center aligned. How can I do that dynamically?
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGo2a.png)

Choose Matrix --> Format --> Field formatting --> "Yeni Teminatlı" --> Alignment --> Centre

I did this, but if this value is a number, the numbers appear in the center. But when there is Number it needs to appear right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

A very funny trick :) is you add some white spaces to the right and adjust until you find the appropriate position for your value "-"

```
" -        "
```

You have to turned off the **Text Wrap** option for as shown below-

[image]

Comment: Hello,

I couldn't. It's like it didn't happen in the image you sent :)

Comment: Can you provide a sample pbix file? (with sample data)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't

Comment: Then you need to explore. This will work.

Comment: Hello again,

I can do this, but this dash doesn't align in the middle of each column because the widths of the columns are different.

Comment: if you have same measure for diffrent column, you have to keep column width same. And if you have separate measure for each column, you have to add whte spaces based on column width.

Comment: I know that column widths are automatic in Power BI. For example, can "car" and "telephone" have the same column width? Thank you.

Comment: Column widths are adjustable.